# Node Menu in Lamp Settings linking keyframes of multiple objects

Tags: animation, node-editor, keyframes

I have a scene that has some lamps that are animated with keyframes they were each created individually and follow separate curves I was trying to save time when i decided to change the size of all 12 lamps at once so I selected them and linked Object Data and adjusted the lamp size i then made the lamps single user.

I've made local, I've made data single user, I've made object animation single user, I've tried everything

The objects are not linked. Changing the emission strength only affects the single selected lamp adding a keyframe to the emission strength however adds keyframes on 6 other lamps and they all snap to that brightness.

Weird thing to me is, i can individually keyframe other settings (such as transform) and it only adds keyframe to selected lamp, but when keyframing the emission strength or color it adds it to all of them, but only adds for the selected when adding keyframe to other settings like lamp size

So only the Node section of the lamp settings seemed to be linked, and nothing else